# Use Data Extension as Inclusion instead of Exclusion

Tags: marketing-cloud, exclusion-script

I have the following issue.
I have a triggered send in the marketing cloud which is triggered directly from commerce cloud. But we are only allowed to send to people with an active OptIn.
So I were thinking about the exclusion script to exclude people with OptIn on false. That works.
BUT completely new clients are synched not that fast. So the trigger is firing and can not exclude the person because they are not yet in the system.

I were thinking about an "inclusion method" because now, if people are not in the list the rowcount is < 1

```
ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("Inclusion_DE", "PersonEmail", EmailAddress)) < 1
```

But now people that are in the DE are not included, so it seems not to work.
So how can I include only people that are in this Data Extension?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have an Exclusion Script that will only allow sends to the contacts that are found in another Data Extension by having that -

```
ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("Inclusion_DE", "PersonEmail", emailaddr)) == 0
```

In other words, if the Email Address matches between Sendable and "Inclusion_DE" Data Extension, then it gets included.

Comment: Perfect, thx. That works :-)